# Converting VB sub procedure to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

In VB, I have classes that look like:

```
Public Class Example
    Public test1 As New List(of String)
    Public test2 As New List(of String)

    Public Sub Init()
        //code logic here
    End Sub
End Class
```

My understanding is that this Sub Init() procedure works like a main method in C#, in that everytime the Example class is used, this method is initialized automatically. Is this a correct understanding? How would this sub procedure be written in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that this Sub Init() procedure works like a main method in C#, in that everytime the Example class is used, this method is initialized automatically.

No, that's not a correct understanding of *either* the `Init` method *or* the `Main` method in C#, as far as I'm aware.

This is *just* a method named `Init`, with nothing special about it. If this were a `New` method, that would correspond to a C# constructor, but that's a different matter.

Your class is equivalent to:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
    public List<string> test1 = new List<string>();
    public List<string> test2 = new List<string>();

    public void Init()
    {
        // code logic here
    }
}
```

It's possible that this class is being used in some framework which automatically looks for `Init` methods and executes them with reflection, but that's not part of the VB language.

Comment: there is also a New method in the code I'm converting -- could you elaborate on that and how you would convert to C#?

Comment: @suhMAN: As already noted in my answer, you just convert that into a constructor in C#. (It *is* a constructor in VB, it's just that constructors in VB are represented using a `Sub` with a name of `New`, whereas in C# they're represented using the type name.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Example
{
public List<string> test1 = new List<string>();

public List<string> test2 = new List<string>();
public void Init()
{
        //code logic here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note...

In old school VB6 there was an "initialize" method in classes that was the equivalent of a modern .Net constructor:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    mvarHeight = 5
End Sub`
```

See [Class_Initialize Changes for Visual Basic 6.0 Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fxtxxwa%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

**Obviously this would only be pertinent if you were converting some very old code!...**